# Typescript Type Assertion operator precendence

Tags: javascript, typescript, logical-operators, operator-precedence

Should i wrap js-ternary operator on 'as' Type Assertion?

```
ios ? TouchableOpacity : View as React.ElementType
```

or, as it always 'comes first' it will use '?:' result?

or better implementation will:

```
(ios ? TouchableOpacity : View) as React.ElementType
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a ? b : c as T` is equivalent to `a ? b : (c as T)`.

[Here's a little demo of the difference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LIQwLgFgdATiB2ATA9gWwBQEoAEA+bUArNgPzYDk52AXNgAzYgDO2TYMAlvAOYBQ6oSLAQoMOfEVIUqtOjmat2XPkA):

```
Math.random() > .5 ? '' : 0 as string
//                        ~~~~~~~~~~~
// Conversion of type 'number' to type 'string' may be a mistake...

// Ok
(Math.random() > .5 ? '' : 0) as string
```